# Postgres code in config.database.yml for Rails Angular app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following this tutorial http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html to create an app using rails an angular js and having issues in making postgres code work

When i run rake db :create i get this error

```
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 71 column 11
```

What username and password should i use in the postgres code in the database.yml file .How do i find out my postgres uername and password .posgres is already installed in the system

Here is the code in database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode


development:
  <<: *default
  database: blog1_development


  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: pguser
  password:


test:
  <<: *default
  database: blog1_test

   adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  username: pguser
  password:
```

Comment: The yaml file you included certainly doesn't have 71 lines, so what about posting it in full?

Comment: BTW so many lines is quite a lot for databases.yml, I would reconsider that

Comment: I have now updated the post with complete code from database.yml file

Comment: The database.yaml doesnt have that many lines originally but the tutorial i am following requires addding these lines

Comment: In the code pasted above there's an extra space in `test` section, before `adapter`. You can only have two spaces in there. Also remove empty lines if they don't separate blocks and check if there are any tabs (as error msg says), should fix it.

Comment: I get this error now     DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol (:postgresql) instead. (called from mon_synchronize at /Users/muhammadatif/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211)
rake aborted!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use password create a password by
opening cmd prompt
enter this to create password

mysqladmin -u pguser password [newpassword]

after creating the password

change your database.yml file
development:

<<: *default

database: blog1_development

development:

adapter: postgresql

encoding: unicode

database: blog_development

pool: 5

username: pguser

password: [new password]

Enter the password correctly give a space after colon<:> in database.yml in password section when entering password